# Taking back user to the beginning of the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a blackjack game via Ruby. I'm working on the introduction section where Ruby will ask if the user is going to play the game with a "Yes or No" option.

If user types "No", Ruby will ask "Are you sure?"
From here, if the user types "No" again, I want Ruby to take the user back to the beginning of the program again.

```
# Blackjack Game introduction

puts "Welcome! Are we ready to play? Yes or No"
answer = gets.chomp

if answer == "Yes"
    puts "Great! What is your name?"
    user_name = gets.chomp
    name = [] << user_name
    puts "Alright #{user_name}! Let's play!"
elsif
    puts "Are you sure you want to exit? Yes or No"
    user_answer = gets.chomp
  if user_answer == "No"
    retry
  end
end
```

"retry" method will give me an error...
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your game is an infinite loop, which the user will break out of. So put around everything:

```
while true

end
```

Then replace `retry` with `break`. (And, at this phase, quality time just reading a tutorial would not kill you.)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want your code inside a `begin` and `end` statement:

```
begin
  puts "Welcome! Are we ready to play? Yes or No"
  answer = gets.chomp

  if answer == "Yes"
    puts "Great! What is your name?"
    user_name = gets.chomp
    name = [] << user_name
    puts "Alright #{user_name}! Let's play!"
  elsif
    puts "Are you sure you want to exit? Yes or No"
    user_answer = gets.chomp
    if user_answer == "No"
      retry
    end
  end
end
```

There is a [great tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) that talks about `retry` and gives examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
puts "Welcome! Are we ready to play? Yes or No"
while play_answer = gets.chomp
  if play_answer == "Yes"
    puts "Great! What is your name?"
    user_name = gets.chomp
    puts "Alright #{user_name}! Let's play!"
  else
    puts "Are you sure you want to exit? Yes or No"
    exit_answer = gets.chomp
    if exit_answer == "Yes"
      puts "Goodbye"
      break
    end
  end
end
```